# Display a string from datagridview to a dbcombo

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a combobox(dbcombo) that has been populated with city names from my database(OLEDB). There's also a datagrid view that displays the contents of this database. 
I want to be able double click on the datagrid view and display one of the row data (i.e the index containing  the city name) in the combo box. i tried something like

```
 combobox1.SelectedItem = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

but doesn't work. How can i get that row index value from the datagrid to be shown in the combobox.

thanks

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out it's got to be like this

combobox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();